# how to fix different font size shown for input fields in chrome and firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, cross-browser

i am noticing in my web app that the same input form font size, currently set to 17px, reads smaller on chrome compared to firefox. i've attached a screenshot.

[image]

is there a more elegant method to resolve this than simply using

```
/*chrome*/
input {
 font-size:17px;
}
/*firefox*/
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
   input {
     font-size:15px;/*reduce font size to match what is seen in chrome*/
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no point in chasing pixels like that between the browsers. Users make a choice to use one of them just because they are different, so I recommend to stop making them an exact copy of each other. What you can do though, is take a look at this, [__normalize.css__](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css). It has some great stuff that will even out the most important things (which again can be opinion-based, but still not bad)

Comment: Are you declaring and using the same font for both browsers? If not, then the browser will select which font to use based on availability and user settings.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what font you're using (or platform (Mac vs Win makes a difference too) , but some browsers render fonts using CLEARTYPE subpixel rendering, some use QUARTZ subpixel rendering (making appearance differ), then others use standard antialias-ing.

A good way around this is to use font-smoothing css in your html or body css:

```
html {
    font-family: /*yourfont*/;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Read more about it and see more examples on [Max Voltar's website](http://maxvoltar.com/archive/-webkit-font-smoothing)

Also note that using em is preferable to using px for measuring your font. Large font sizes are especially harmed by pixelation if you don't use font smoothing, so in order to keep accessible text especially, it's better to use ems (this way you can still use large type sizes).